# How to fix 'page.target is not a function' in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to use the Devtools Protocol with Puppeteer, but it throws the following error:

> TypeError: page.target is not a function

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  // Use Puppeteer to launch a browser and open a page.
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Create a raw DevTools protocol session to talk to the page.
  const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
})();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you check which version of Puppeteer you have ?

Comment: Dang! For some reason I was thinking that I'm using the latest version... but it's `0.13.0` :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest version of Puppeteer.

```
"dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "latest"
}
```